# Can a ListView have and a kendoDropTarget method and a kendoSortable method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have an application that has 2 ListViews.  I have one ListView that lists products and I'm able to drag the products over to the other ListView.  I'm able to drag over the items.  The issue that I'm running into is when I try to resort the items on the second ListView.  The application breaks.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

I've copied over some of my code to see if someone can spot the issue

```
$("#products-list").kendoListView({
    selectable: "single",
    dataSource: productsList,
    template: kendo.template($('#item-template').html())
});

$("#products-list").kendoDraggable({
    filter: ".item",
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone();
    },
    kendoDropTarget: "#selected-products-list",
});

$("#selected-products-list").kendoListView({
    dataSource: selectedProducts,
    template: kendo.template($('#selected-item-template').html())
});

$("#selected-products-list").kendoDropTarget({
    drop: function (e) { // Apply the changes to the data after an item is dropped.
        var draggableElement = e.draggable.currentTarget,
            dataItem = productsList.getByUid(draggableElement.data("uid")); // Find the corresponding dataItem by uid.

        selectedProducts.add(dataItem); 
    }
});

$("#selected-products-list").kendoSortable({
    filter: ".item",
    cursor: "move",
    placeholder: function (element) {
        return element.clone().css("opacity", 0.1);
    },
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone().removeClass("k-state-selected");
    },
    change: function (e) {
        var oldIndex = e.oldIndex,
            newIndex = e.newIndex,
            data = selectedProducts.data(),
            dataItem = selectedProducts.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));
        selectedProducts.remove(dataItem);
        selectedProducts.insert(newIndex, dataItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in `connectWith` option? https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/linkedlists

Comment: I'm still a student of kendo and I was unaware of that would work.  There are 2 potential issues with this.  The customer might complain about the sorting on the items on the left.  Is it possible to make a list that has sub categories under each item?